# When publishing message in laravel through kafka producer getting error code -185: 'Local: Timed out'

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Below is my code from controller file

```
use Junges\Kafka\Facades\Kafka;

use Junges\Kafka\Message\Message;   

public function produceKafka(){
        $message = new Message( headers: [], body: ['id' => '1212121']);
        Kafka::publishOn('192.168.201.197:9092', 'topic2')  
        ->withConfigOption('acks', '0')
        ->withMessage($message)
        ->send();

        echo 'messgae sent succesfully ';
    }
```

When I call this method it return error
Your message could not be published. Flush returned with error code -185: 'Local: Timed out'.

**For config Information :**

```
'brokers' => '192.168.201.197:9092',
'consumer_group_id' => 'my-group',
'consumer_timeout_ms' => 10000,
'offset_reset' => 'earliest',
'auto_commit' => true,
'sleep_on_error' =>5,
'partition' => 0,
'compression' =>'none',
'debug' => true,
```

Comment: Is that IP address correct? Has this code worked before?

Comment: No i am testing on my local system first time

Comment: Then why aren't you using `localhost:9092`? By default, Kafka doesn't bind to external ip address